# Shopify app and external app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, shopify

I want use Shopify app as backend for Android app.

I need send products in json format from backend to Android app. My Shopify app generated  by [this tutorial.](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/blob/master/README.md)

When I want get Products

```
@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 10})
```

I must use

```
around_filter :shopify_session
```

but when my Android app send request, this filter does not allow to execute it.

How do I get out of this situation?

Comment: why would you want to exclude it? this is what keeps your app connected to the shopify api.

Comment: My android app can not get response from Shopify app. (by reason of this filter, if I'm not mistaken.) 
There are ways to modify this filter?